# Find $c=a\times b$ such that $c$ has digits from either $a$ or $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> *The problem statement:* Two numbers $2 \leq a, b <100$ are multiplied,
>   the resultant number has same digits of **either** **$a$ or $b$**
>   **only**, how many such numbers $(c)$ are there and which are they?

Example: $10 \times 10 = 100 $, on the left hand side we have $0,1$ and on the right hand side also we have $0,1$.

Since $99\times 99 =9801$, $c$ cannot be more than $4$ digits

Let $c=c_4c_3c_2c_1=c_4\times 1000+c_3\times 100+c_2\times 10+c_1$

- When both $a,b$ are one digit, there are $ {8\choose 1}\times {8\choose 1}=8\times8=64, 64-28=36$, (subtracting the repeated multiplications)
- When both $a,b$ are two digit, there are $ {90\choose 1}\times {90\choose 1}=90\times90=8100, 8100-4005=4095$, (subtracting the repeated multiplications)
- When one is one digit and second is two digits, $ {8\choose 1}+ {90 \choose 1} = 8+90=89$, (No repeated multiplications)

So, there are $36+4095+89=4220$ multiplications to be checked.  What to do next?

In another approach, $c=c_4c_3c_2c_1$, since $c_4,c_3,c_2,c_1$ should either belong to $a$ or $b$

- $a$ can be formed in $4 \choose 1$ ways, $b$ can be formed in $3 \choose 2$ ways, so there are $4 \times (3\times 2!)=24$ such numbers (this case may be invalid as one digit from $c$ is left out, but what if $c$ has a digit repeated?)
- $a$ can be formed in $4 \choose 2$ ways, $b$ can be formed in $4 \choose 2$ ways, for each selection, rearrangement produces another number, so there are $6\times 2!=12$ such numbers.

How to find these $36$ numbers ?

Comment: Pair numbers are 18 $(10, 10), (11, 10), (12, 10), (13, 10), (14, 10), (15, 10), (16, 10), 
(17, 10), (18, 10), (19, 10), (21, 10), (31, 10), (41, 10), (51, 10), 
(61, 10), (71, 10), (81, 10), (91, 10)$
Maybe you have counted the symmetrics, too...

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the interpretation of the question:

- Do the pairs $(a,b)$ have to be unique up to swapping (ie can we count both $3\times 51$ and $51\times3$)?
- Do the result have to be a permutation of the digits (ie must all the digits appear the same number of times)?
- Or do all digits have to appear at all?
- Do leading zeroes count?

Since there are only $98\times98=9604$ possible products we can test all cases and check if the product matches whatever criterion we interpret it as.

But we can skip some products. We have for example that the digits of $a$ and $b$ must both add up to something divisible $3$ or not (because of the rule for determining division by three). The same applies to adding up to something divisible by $9$. This reduces the possibilities to less than half.

If you skip reversals I get $226$ combinations, with reversions it's $2\times 226 = 451$ because we have one self-multiplication ($10\times10=100$). They are:

$$\begin{matrix}
20 &= 2\times10 \hspace{20pt}22 &= 2\times11 \hspace{20pt}122 &= 2\times61 \hspace{20pt}30 &= 3\times10 \\
33 &= 3\times11 \hspace{20pt}153 &= 3\times51 \hspace{20pt}40 &= 4\times10 \hspace{20pt}44 &= 4\times11 \\
64 &= 4\times16 \hspace{20pt}50 &= 5\times10 \hspace{20pt}55 &= 5\times11 \hspace{20pt}95 &= 5\times19 \\
155 &= 5\times31 \hspace{20pt}60 &= 6\times10 \hspace{20pt}66 &= 6\times11 \hspace{20pt}126 &= 6\times21 \\
444 &= 6\times74 \hspace{20pt}70 &= 7\times10 \hspace{20pt}77 &= 7\times11 \hspace{20pt}80 &= 8\times10 \\
88 &= 8\times11 \hspace{20pt}344 &= 8\times43 \hspace{20pt}688 &= 8\times86 \hspace{20pt}90 &= 9\times10 \\
99 &= 9\times11 \hspace{20pt}225 &= 9\times25 \hspace{20pt}333 &= 9\times37 \hspace{20pt}100 &= 10\times10 \\
110 &= 10\times11 \hspace{20pt}120 &= 10\times12 \hspace{20pt}130 &= 10\times13 \hspace{20pt}140 &= 10\times14 \\
150 &= 10\times15 \hspace{20pt}160 &= 10\times16 \hspace{20pt}170 &= 10\times17 \hspace{20pt}180 &= 10\times18 \\
190 &= 10\times19 \hspace{20pt}200 &= 10\times20 \hspace{20pt}210 &= 10\times21 \hspace{20pt}220 &= 10\times22 \\
230 &= 10\times23 \hspace{20pt}240 &= 10\times24 \hspace{20pt}250 &= 10\times25 \hspace{20pt}260 &= 10\times26 \\
270 &= 10\times27 \hspace{20pt}280 &= 10\times28 \hspace{20pt}290 &= 10\times29 \hspace{20pt}300 &= 10\times30 \\
310 &= 10\times31 \hspace{20pt}320 &= 10\times32 \hspace{20pt}330 &= 10\times33 \hspace{20pt}340 &= 10\times34 \\
350 &= 10\times35 \hspace{20pt}360 &= 10\times36 \hspace{20pt}370 &= 10\times37 \hspace{20pt}380 &= 10\times38 \\
390 &= 10\times39 \hspace{20pt}400 &= 10\times40 \hspace{20pt}410 &= 10\times41 \hspace{20pt}420 &= 10\times42 \\
430 &= 10\times43 \hspace{20pt}440 &= 10\times44 \hspace{20pt}450 &= 10\times45 \hspace{20pt}460 &= 10\times46 \\
470 &= 10\times47 \hspace{20pt}480 &= 10\times48 \hspace{20pt}490 &= 10\times49 \hspace{20pt}500 &= 10\times50 \\
510 &= 10\times51 \hspace{20pt}520 &= 10\times52 \hspace{20pt}530 &= 10\times53 \hspace{20pt}540 &= 10\times54 \\
550 &= 10\times55 \hspace{20pt}560 &= 10\times56 \hspace{20pt}570 &= 10\times57 \hspace{20pt}580 &= 10\times58 \\
590 &= 10\times59 \hspace{20pt}600 &= 10\times60 \hspace{20pt}610 &= 10\times61 \hspace{20pt}620 &= 10\times62 \\
630 &= 10\times63 \hspace{20pt}640 &= 10\times64 \hspace{20pt}650 &= 10\times65 \hspace{20pt}660 &= 10\times66 \\
670 &= 10\times67 \hspace{20pt}680 &= 10\times68 \hspace{20pt}690 &= 10\times69 \hspace{20pt}700 &= 10\times70 \\
710 &= 10\times71 \hspace{20pt}720 &= 10\times72 \hspace{20pt}730 &= 10\times73 \hspace{20pt}740 &= 10\times74 \\
750 &= 10\times75 \hspace{20pt}760 &= 10\times76 \hspace{20pt}770 &= 10\times77 \hspace{20pt}780 &= 10\times78 \\
790 &= 10\times79 \hspace{20pt}800 &= 10\times80 \hspace{20pt}810 &= 10\times81 \hspace{20pt}820 &= 10\times82 \\
830 &= 10\times83 \hspace{20pt}840 &= 10\times84 \hspace{20pt}850 &= 10\times85 \hspace{20pt}860 &= 10\times86 \\
870 &= 10\times87 \hspace{20pt}880 &= 10\times88 \hspace{20pt}890 &= 10\times89 \hspace{20pt}900 &= 10\times90 \\
910 &= 10\times91 \hspace{20pt}920 &= 10\times92 \hspace{20pt}930 &= 10\times93 \hspace{20pt}940 &= 10\times94 \\
950 &= 10\times95 \hspace{20pt}960 &= 10\times96 \hspace{20pt}970 &= 10\times97 \hspace{20pt}980 &= 10\times98 \\
990 &= 10\times99 \hspace{20pt}220 &= 11\times20 \hspace{20pt}330 &= 11\times30 \hspace{20pt}440 &= 11\times40 \\
550 &= 11\times50 \hspace{20pt}616 &= 11\times56 \hspace{20pt}660 &= 11\times60 \hspace{20pt}770 &= 11\times70 \\
880 &= 11\times80 \hspace{20pt}990 &= 11\times90 \hspace{20pt}816 &= 12\times68 \hspace{20pt}312 &= 13\times24 \\
325 &= 13\times25 \hspace{20pt}1118 &= 13\times86 \hspace{20pt}1131 &= 13\times87 \hspace{20pt}322 &= 14\times23 \\
434 &= 14\times31 \hspace{20pt}644 &= 14\times46 \hspace{20pt}966 &= 14\times69 \hspace{20pt}1148 &= 14\times82 \\
555 &= 15\times37 \hspace{20pt}1050 &= 15\times70 \hspace{20pt}1155 &= 15\times77 \hspace{20pt}1395 &= 15\times93 \\
640 &= 16\times40 \hspace{20pt}714 &= 17\times42 \hspace{20pt}731 &= 17\times43 \hspace{20pt}1080 &= 18\times60 \\
1116 &= 18\times62 \hspace{20pt}1188 &= 18\times66 \hspace{20pt}950 &= 19\times50 \hspace{20pt}500 &= 20\times25 \\
1020 &= 20\times51 \hspace{20pt}1220 &= 20\times61 \hspace{20pt}525 &= 21\times25 \hspace{20pt}777 &= 21\times37 \\
1050 &= 21\times50 \hspace{20pt}1113 &= 21\times53 \hspace{20pt}1155 &= 21\times55 \hspace{20pt}1218 &= 21\times58 \\
1260 &= 21\times60 \hspace{20pt}1323 &= 21\times63 \hspace{20pt}1575 &= 21\times75 \hspace{20pt}1827 &= 21\times87 \\
1911 &= 21\times91 \hspace{20pt}1995 &= 21\times95 \hspace{20pt}1122 &= 22\times51 \hspace{20pt}624 &= 24\times26 \\
1224 &= 24\times51 \hspace{20pt}1464 &= 24\times61 \hspace{20pt}2232 &= 24\times93 \hspace{20pt}1525 &= 25\times61 \\
1775 &= 25\times71 \hspace{20pt}2000 &= 25\times80 \hspace{20pt}2225 &= 25\times89 \hspace{20pt}2250 &= 25\times90 \\
2325 &= 25\times93 \hspace{20pt}2080 &= 26\times80 \hspace{20pt}2262 &= 26\times87 \hspace{20pt}2288 &= 26\times88 \\
2444 &= 26\times94 \hspace{20pt}2187 &= 27\times81 \hspace{20pt}1148 &= 28\times41 \hspace{20pt}2688 &= 28\times96 \\
1530 &= 30\times51 \hspace{20pt}1116 &= 31\times36 \hspace{20pt}1333 &= 31\times43 \hspace{20pt}1488 &= 31\times48 \\
1550 &= 31\times50 \hspace{20pt}2232 &= 31\times72 \hspace{20pt}1312 &= 32\times41 \hspace{20pt}2272 &= 32\times71 \\
2912 &= 32\times91 \hspace{20pt}1435 &= 35\times41 \hspace{20pt}3395 &= 35\times97 \hspace{20pt}2232 &= 36\times62 \\
3330 &= 37\times90 \hspace{20pt}3393 &= 39\times87 \hspace{20pt}2142 &= 42\times51 \hspace{20pt}2646 &= 42\times63 \\
2666 &= 43\times62 \hspace{20pt}3397 &= 43\times79 \hspace{20pt}3440 &= 43\times80 \hspace{20pt}3483 &= 43\times81 \\
3913 &= 43\times91 \hspace{20pt}3999 &= 43\times93 \hspace{20pt}4050 &= 45\times90 \hspace{20pt}4455 &= 45\times99 \\
2444 &= 47\times52 \hspace{20pt}4428 &= 54\times82 \hspace{20pt}4644 &= 54\times86 \hspace{20pt}4914 &= 54\times91 \\
4788 &= 57\times84 \hspace{20pt}5568 &= 58\times96 \hspace{20pt}4440 &= 60\times74 \hspace{20pt}5185 &= 61\times85 \\
5355 &= 63\times85 \hspace{20pt}5655 &= 65\times87 \hspace{20pt}5915 &= 65\times91 \hspace{20pt}6188 &= 68\times91 \\
5865 &= 69\times85 \hspace{20pt}6555 &= 69\times95 \hspace{20pt}5775 &= 75\times77 \hspace{20pt}6080 &= 76\times80 \\
6688 &= 76\times88 \hspace{20pt}6916 &= 76\times91 \hspace{20pt}6992 &= 76\times92 \hspace{20pt}6880 &= 80\times86 \\
7917 &= 87\times91 \hspace{20pt}8918 &= 91\times98 \hspace{20pt}
\end{matrix}$$

If you count leading zeroes you also have these $9$ possibilities:

$$\begin{align}
50 &= 02\times25 \\
102 &= 02\times51 \\
105 &= 05\times21 \\
108 &= 06\times18 \\
105 &= 07\times15 \\
200 &= 08\times25 \\
208 &= 08\times26 \\
608 &= 08\times76 \\
405 &= 09\times45 \\
\end{align}$$

Of course I haven't done these tables and calculations by hand, they are computer generated, for example the first table is created by this python program:

```
import itertools

cnt = 0

def abc():
    for a in range(2,100):
        if a < 2:
            continue
        for b in range(2,100):
            if b < 2:
                continue

            if a > b:
                continue

            c = a*b

            yield ("{0}".format(a),
                   "{0}".format(b),
                   "{0}".format(c))

for a, b, c in abc():
    if all(cj in a+b for cj in c):
        cnt += 1

        if cnt % 4:
            print( "{c} &= {a}\\times{b} \\hspace{{20pt}}".format(a=a, b=b, c=c ), end = '' )
        else:
            print( "{c} &= {a}\\times{b} \\\\".format(a=a, b=b, c=c ) )

print()
print(cnt)
```

Comment: a.b=b.a, number of times a digit repeats on both the side is not important, pls don't count leading zeros

Comment: you have posted 608=8*76, 0 which belongs to c is not there in either a or b

Comment: @Vikram The list is computer generated (of course) - probably a bug in my program which I've hopefully corrected.